# Manipulating JSON data with SQL in Oracle

Tags: json, oracle

I have a CLOB field in my Oracle (v12.2) table which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dmo_person (
    per_id RAW(16) CONSTRAINT NN_per_id NOT NULL,
    per_name VARCHAR2(128),
    per_tags CLOB CONSTRAINT dmo_pers_json_0 CHECK (per_tags IS JSON),
    CONSTRAINT sko_person_pk_0 PRIMARY KEY (per_id)
);
```

The JSON data has the following structure:

```
insert into dmo_person
 ( per_id, per_name, per_tags  )
values
 (
 sys_guid(),
 'John Doe',
 '{ "perm_admin" : 1, "perm_fileuser" : 0, "perm_subcon" : 1} ',
 );
```

So my question: Using an SQL update statement, how can I add another value like `"perm_bigboss" : 1`  to my CLOB? And is there an easy way to set a single value `"perm_admin" : 0` using SQL?

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768597/how-to-update-a-part-of-json-string-in-oracle-12c

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `PUT` method of `JSON_OBJECT_T` to add/set a single value.

Assuming that you update a single row( with a `where` clause), you may use this block. If there are multiple rows, use a loop or cursor.

```
 DECLARE
  v_pertags dmo_person.per_tags%TYPE;
  v_json_obj JSON_OBJECT_T;
  v_new_pertags dmo_person.per_tags%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT per_tags
  INTO   v_pertags
  FROM   dmo_person; --where clause
  v_json_obj := TREAT(json_element_t.PARSE(v_pertags) AS json_object_t);
  v_json_obj.PUT('perm_bigboss' , 1);
  v_json_obj.PUT('perm_admin', 0);
  v_new_pertags := v_json_obj.to_string;

UPDATE dmo_person
  SET    per_tags = v_new_pertags; --where clause
END;
/
```

[**LIVESQL DEMO**](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f76zgzo8l8chvug1uie3dplb6)

Comment: Nice, thank you! No idea where I could have find this within Oracle documentation ..

Comment: JSON Documentation for 12.2 https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/toc.htm 

For PL/SQL in particular  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/using-PLSQL-object-types-for-JSON.html#GUID-F0561593-D0B9-44EA-9C8C-ACB6AA9474EE

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle 11g version Json manupulation is not supported. So we must use basic functions : SUBSTR / INSTR / SUBSTR

```
create OR replace FUNCTION Get_Value(data_request VARCHAR2, s_key VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS s_Value VARCHAR2(2000);

index1 integer := 0;
index2 integer := 0;

BEGIN 

s_Value := '';

SELECT INSTR(data_request, '"' || s_key || '":"' , 1, 1) INTO index1 FROM dual;

IF (index1 > 0) THEN
    index1 := index1 + LENGTH('"' || s_key || '":"') ;
    s_Value := SUBSTR(data_request, index1, LENGTH(data_request));
    SELECT INSTR(s_Value, '"', 1, 1) INTO index2 FROM dual;
    s_Value := SUBSTR(data_request, index1, index2-1);
END IF;

RETURN(s_Value); 

END;
```

Assume, we have a table 'tableName' having column 'data_request like :          {"ip":"127.0.0.1","username":"userTest"}

We can then parse the json string like this :

```
SELECT data_request,  
Get_Value(data_request, 'numeroDeCompte'), Get_Value(data_request, 'ip') ip, 
Get_Value(data_request, 'username') username 
FROM tableName
```